# is there a cleaner way of passing variadic data?

Tags: c++, multithreading, networking

How to pass variadic data from one function to another in cleaner way then this ?

Demonstation code:

```
void * variadic_data = nullptr;

void send_1(){
   if(sendto(...)){
       variadic_data = static_cast<void *>(new int(123)); // from here
   }
}

void send_2(){
   if(sendto(...)){
       variadic_data = static_cast<void *>(new std::string("test"));
   }
}

void task(){
    ...
    do {
        i_result =  recv(...);
        std::string message(buff, i_result);
        if(message == ...){
            int * int_1 = static_cast<int *>(variadic_data); // to here
            ...
            delete int_1 ;
        } else if (message == ...) {
            std::string * str_1 = static_cast<std::string *>(variadic_data);
            ...
            delete str_1;
        }
    } while(i_result != 0 && i_result != SOCKET_ERROR);
}
```

I have extra thread with recv and few other threads with sendto function, many of sendto have local variables which differ and are needed after the responce in recv thread. I thought that blocking recv in extra thread is common way. Is this simply bad app design ? Should i create message manager and pick right after the sendto ?

Comment: Why does `variadic_data` have multiple types of conents? Why not separate variables? Why is it a global? Why does `std::variadic` not work? Why does this look like a message pump where the extra data is stored in globals instead of in the message?

Comment: @MooingDuck `variadic_data` have multiple types of content because i try to avoid having separated variables for each send local type. It's global because of access from each function. By `std::variadic` you mean variadic arguments ? they do not work because the task is already running. Why sending extra data in message when server does not need them at all ?

Comment: Sorry, I'd meant `std::variant`. But you shouldn't have globals. In general, mutable globals are almost always a bad idea, and cause bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), eg:

```
std::variant<int, std::string> variadic_data;

...

variadic_data = 123;

...

variadic_data = std::string("test");

... 

if (message == ...) {
    int int_1 = std::get<int>(variadic_data);
    ...
}
else if (message == ...) {
    std::string str_1 = std::get<std::string>(variadic_data);
    ...
}
```

Or, use [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) instead, eg:

```
std::any variadic_data;

...

variadic_data = 123;
// or variadic_data = std::make_any<int>(123);

...

variadic_data = std::string("test");
// or variadic_data = std::make_any<std::string>("test");

... 

if (message == ...) {
    int int_1 = std::any_cast<int>(variadic_data);
    ...
}
else if (message == ...) {
    std::string str_1 = std::any_cast<std::string>(variadic_data);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I approve of this (but I misread the question initially as defining C-style variadic argument lists)

Comment: this look more cleaner then `std::any` but i'll use it because i don't have to explicitly specific types (have a lot of them)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can usually use a template function.

In c++17 (or with Boost) you can use `std::any`.

In your particular case I'd use `std::function` to type-erase the handlers.

Comment: I was going to make an example, but it turns out I don't acually understand your code. So, maybe take my last line with a grain of salt as well.